# how to pass the value selected in an HTML table to a javascript function

Tags: javascript, html

I have three tables in my HTML form. Each table has different number of rows and upon double click of any row its value should be passed to a javascript function. These passed values should get appended to a text box present in the same form.

I have given Ids to all three tables and am passing this tableId to the function. Also, how to retrieve the value selected from the table into this javascript function.

What I have done so far is below. A small snippet of one table and the function. Am a newbie to HTML, so hoping for a few helpful answers. :)

```
    <table id="functionTable" >
            <tr>
               <td class="groupObjectTitle" nowrap>Functions</td>
            </tr>
            <td>
            <div class="easyui-panel">
                        <li>
                            <span>Mathematical</span>
                            <ul id="mathFunctions">
                                <li> <a href="javascript:" ondblclick="transferText('functionTable')">&nbsp; + </a></li>
                            ........
function transferText(table){
        var i;
        var k;
        var tabs= document.getElementById(table);
        alert("transferText called on double click");

        for (i=0;i<tabs.rows.length;i++){
            alert(tabs.rows[i].selected);    
            <!-- How to retrieve the value from the selected row. -->

        }
    }
```

Comment: What are the ID's of the other tables?   You cannot have them be the same.

Answer (score 1):

---

**Make sure your table ID's are *NOT* the SAME!**

---

> Solution 1

Use `this` and pass it as an argument to your function.

**html**

```
<a id="somevalue" href="javascript:" ondblclick="transferText('functionTable', this)">&nbsp; + </a>
```

**javascript**

```
    function transferText(table, element) {
        //element = clicked elment, so if you need the ID or some other data..   
        var elementId = element.id;
    }
```

---

> Solution 2 (html5 req)

Use the **html5** [data](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes) attribute.

**html**

```
<a id="myid" data-mydata1="somedatavalue" data-mydata2="someothervalue" href="javascript:" ondblclick="transferText('functionTable', this)">&nbsp; + </a>
```

**javascript**

```
 function transferText(table, value) {
      var mydata = document.querySelector('#myid');
      var data1 = value.dataset.mydata1;
      var data2 = value.dataset.mydata2;
      //etc...
  }
```

Comment: The tableIds of all tables is offcourse different. In Solution 1, can you please tell me how do I fetch the value of the row selected inside the javascript function transferText. I made the function call as onclick="transferText('tableId', this)" and then tried to access element.value inside transferText function but it comes out to be undefined.

Comment: That's because "this" refers to the link that was clicked.  I'm not sure what you mean by row value?  What element are you trying to get the value of?   Or are you trying to get the innerHtml of an element such as <td>innerHtml</td>

Comment: When you say row value are you trying to get the entire html of that row with td's included ?